# Compatibility error that occurs during Firebase Functions deployment

Tags: firebase

The following error has occurred.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: functions@undefined
npm ERR! Found: firebase-admin@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-admin
npm ERR!   firebase-admin@"^111.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer firebase-admin@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from firebase-functions@4.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-functions
npm ERR!   firebase-functions@"^4.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-19T05_41_15_922Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-19T05_41_15_922Z-debug-0.log
```

After researching a solution, I was advised to use the following command, but the issue still remains unresolved.

```
npm install --force
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Can anyone help me with a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue installing dependencies for Firebase functions. What worked for me was going into the "package.json" file within the "functions" folder and changing

```
"firebase-admin": "^111.5.0"
```

to

```
"firebase-admin": "^11.0.0"
```

AFTER running firebase init functions, but before installing the dependencies with npm. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still experiencing this problem for firebase-admin:  12.0.0, update firebase-function-test in devDependencies to 3.1.1 as shown below:

"firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.1",